# R - simple Record Linkage - the next step ?

Tags: r, record, linkage, data-cleaning

I am trying to do some simple direct linkage with the `library('RecordLinkage')`.

So I only have one vector

```
tv3 = c("TOURDEFRANCE", 'TOURDEFRANCE', "TOURDE FRANCE", 
"TOURDE FRANZ", "GET FRESH")
```

The function that I need is `compare.dedup` of the `library('RecordLinkage')` and I get :

```
compare.dedup(as.data.frame(tv3))$pairs

$pairs
id1 id2 tv3 is_match
1    1   2   1       NA
2    1   3   0       NA
3    1   4   0       NA
4    1   5   0       NA
5    2   3   0       NA
....
```

**I have trouble finding documentation for the next step.** How do I then compare and find my similar pair ?

So I found the distance `jarowinkler()` but it returns only pairs. Basically, you can only do `jarowinkler(tv3[1], tv3)` one by one.

So I am asking : do you need to do your own loop to get your result or is there a more direct way from the `compare.dedup` function ?

```
mat = matrix(0, length(tv3), length(tv3))

for(j in 1:length(tv3)){
  for(i in 1:length(tv3)){
    { mat[i,j] = jarowinkler(tv3[j], tv3[i]) }
  }
}
```

The dissimilarity matrix

```
> mat
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.9846154 0.9333333 0.5240741
[2,] 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.9846154 0.9333333 0.5240741
[3,] 0.9846154 0.9846154 1.0000000 0.9525641 0.5133903
[4,] 0.9333333 0.9333333 0.9525641 1.0000000 0.5240741
[5,] 0.5240741 0.5240741 0.5133903 0.5240741 1.0000000
```

**What I want to do** is simply attribute for *similar* object (`"TOURDEFRANCE", 'TOURDEFRANCE', "TOURDE FRANCE", "TOURDE FRANZ"`), one of the possible *similar* object names.

How could I set a cut-off, let's say `0.90`, on my dissimilarity matrix and then `retreive` all the rows of the *similar* object ?

If my data are in a dataframe

```
             tv3
1  TOURDEFRANCE
2  TOURDEFRANCE
3 TOURDE FRANCE
4  TOURDE FRANZ
5     GET FRESH
```

Do something like `which` `cut-off > 0.90` and retreive the corresponding rows ?

Any help for this simple Record Linkage is very welcome !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28884716/2098723), here's an example that should work for you:

```
tv3 = as.data.frame(c("TOURDEFRANCE", 'TOURDEFRANCE', "TOURDE FRANCE", 
    "TOURDE FRANZ", "GET FRESH"))
colnames(tv3) <- "name"

tv3 %>% compare.dedup(strcmp = TRUE) %>%
        epiWeights() %>%
        epiClassify(0.5) %>%
        getPairs(show = "links", single.rows = TRUE) -> matches
```

In result, the `matches` dataframe should help you determining thresholds (set in `epiClassify()`).