# How to fuzzy match text in a column and then replace with a consensus in R

Tags: r, fuzzy-comparison, stringdist

I have a dataframe as follows

```
FName  LName  
Ayeko   Seki
Ayeko   Seki
Ayeko   Seki
Ayeko   Zeki
Aveko   Seki
Avoo    Zooki
Jacques Bergmann.
Jacques Burgman
J       Bergman
Jacques Bergmann
Jacques Bergmann
Jacques Bergmann
Jacques Bergmann
David   Goliath
```

`J Bergman`, `Jacques Bergmann.`, `Jacques Burgman` and `Jacques Bergmann` are the same person as are the first five entries, but not the sixth or last. I would like to try to fuzzy match the names across the two columns and then replace them with a consensus (or the most common among the fuzzy matches I guess is the alternative) so that the outputted data frame should be:

```
FName  LName  
Ayeko   Seki
Avoo    Zooki
Jacques Bergmann
David   Goliath
```

I have tried using `stringdist()` but the issue I am having really is with a) getting the consensus match and b) then replacing the matches with the consensus

Comment: Please show how you used `stringdist`

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904182/word2vec-for-text-mining-categories/35904557#35904557) - you can apply it 1:1 on your example.

Comment: Hi lukeA.  Thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't quite do it- how do I then replace the original column text values with the fuzzy matched one?