# Generating a unique ID column for large dataset with the RecordLinkage package

Tags: r, duplicates, record, linkage, data-linking

I am trying to generate a unique ID column using the RecordLinkage package. I have successfully done so when working with smaller datasets (<= 1,000,000), but have not been able to reproduce this result for larger datasets (> 1,000,000) that use different (but similar) functions in the package. I am given multiple identifier variables for which I want to generate a unique ID despite the fact that there may be some errors (near matches) or duplicates in the records.

Given some data frame of identifiers:

```
data(RLdata500)
df_identifiers <- RLdata500
```

This is the code for the smaller datesets (which work):

```
df_identifiers <- df_identifiers %>% mutate(ID = 1:nrow(df_identifiers))
rpairs <- compare.dedup(df_identifiers)
p=epiWeights(rpairs)
classify <- epiClassify(p,0.3)
matches <- getPairs(object = classify, show = "links", single.rows = TRUE)

# this code writes an "ID" column that is the same for similar identifiers
classify <- matches %>% arrange(ID.1) %>% filter(!duplicated(ID.2))
df_identifiers$ID_prior <- df_identifiers$ID

# merge matching information with the original data
df_identifiers <- left_join(df_identifiers, matches %>% select(ID.1,ID.2), by=c("ID"="ID.2"))

# replace matches in ID with the thing they match with from ID.1
df_identifiers$ID <- ifelse(is.na(df_identifiers$ID.1), df_identifiers$ID, df_identifiers$ID.1)
```

This approach is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28884716/4700548). But this code does not seem to be extensible when applied towards larger datasets when using other functions. For example, the big data equivalent of `compare.dedup` is `RLBigDataDedup`, whose `RLBigData` class support similar functions such as `epiWeights`, `epiClassify`, `getPairs`, etc. Replacing `compare.dedup` with `RLBigDataDedup` does not work in this situation.

Consider the following attempt for large datasets:

```
df_identifiers <- df_identifiers %>% mutate(ID = 1:nrow(df_identifiers))
rpairs <- RLBigDataDedup(df_identifiers)
p=epiWeights(rpairs)
( . . . )
```

Here, the remaining code is almost identical to that of the first. Although `epiWeights` and `epiClassify` work on the `RLBigData` class as expected, `getPairs` does not. The function `getPairs` does not use the `show = "links"` argument. Because of this, all subsequent code does not work.

Is there a different approach that needs to be taken to generate a column of unique IDs when working with larger datasets in the `RLBigData` class, or is this just a limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, import the following libraries:

```
library(RecordLinkage)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
```

Consider these example datasets from the RecordLinkage package:

```
data(RLdata500)
data(RLdata10000)
```

Assume we care about these matching variables and threshold:

```
matching_variables <- c("fname_c1", "lname_c1", "by", "bm", "bd")
threshold <- 0.5
```

The record linkage for SMALL datasets is as follows:

```
RLdata <- RLdata500
df_names <- data.frame(RLdata[, matching_variables])
df_names %>%
  compare.dedup() %>%
  epiWeights() %>%
  epiClassify(threshold) %>%
  getPairs(show = "links", single.rows = TRUE) -> matching_data
```

Here, the following SMALL data manipulation may be applied to append the appropriate IDs to the given dataset (same code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884716/using-recordlinkage-to-add-a-column-with-a-number-for-each-person)):

```
RLdata_ID <- left_join(mutate(df_names, ID = 1:nrow(df_names)),
                       select(matching_data, id1, id2) %>%
                         arrange(id1) %>% filter(!duplicated(id2)),
                       by = c("ID" = "id2")) %>%
  mutate(ID = ifelse(is.na(id1), ID, id1)) %>%
  select(-id1)
RLdata$ID <- RLdata_ID$ID
```

The equivalent code for LARGE datasets is as follows:

```
RLdata <- RLdata10000
df_names <- data.frame(RLdata[, matching_variables])
df_names %>%
  RLBigDataDedup() %>%
  epiWeights() %>%
  epiClassify(threshold) %>%
  getPairs(filter.link = "link", single.rows = TRUE) -> matching_data
```

Here, the following LARGE data manipulation may be applied to append the appropriate IDs to the given dataset (similar to code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884716/using-recordlinkage-to-add-a-column-with-a-number-for-each-person)):

```
RLdata_ID <- left_join(mutate(df_names, ID = 1:nrow(df_names)),
                       select(matching_data, id.1, id.2) %>%
                         arrange(id.1) %>% filter(!duplicated(id.2)),
                       by = c("ID" = "id.2")) %>%
  mutate(ID = ifelse(is.na(id.1), ID, id.1)) %>%
  select(-id.1)
RLdata$ID <- RLdata_ID$ID
```